# Intuition behind linear differential operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-algebras

In an introductory course on linear differential equations I was introduced to an operator $D$ of order $n, \frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ and subsequently, all problems thereafter were solved by treating it as any other real number. For instance to solve a linear O.D.E,

> $a_0(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2(x)y=0$
> $a_0(x)D^2y+a_1(x)Dy+a_2(x)y=0$
> $(a_0(x)D^2+a_1(x)D+a_2(x))y=0$
> $(D-m_1)(D-m_2)y=0$

The last step is not intuitive at all. How can we justify such a treatment of $D$? Can anyone explain/point me to a reference?

Comment: Well I mean if you did the step in reverse from last step to third step then it's valid right

Comment: The last step is not possible in general, it is only completely justified if the coefficients are constant. The "reduction of order" method could be interpreted as such a factorization in the general situation.